# Two NSwindows with the same view but diffrent functions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsview, nswindow

i'm working with painting app and i want to make two different NSWindows with the same view and using different functions on it. Any ideas how to do that? I'm thinking about creating one window with view with interface builder and other programmatically?

Comment: I'm getting this error when second window is loading "/SourceCache/CoreImage/CoreImage-8.4.0/API/CIContext.mm:425: CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect:: CoreImage: detected potential division by zero." any ideas how to fix it or any solution how to make second window with the same view?